# iOS AVResourceLoaderDelegate error -12881 when passing HLS content

Tags: ios, media-player

I am working on an app that uses a custom cache to stream HLS formatted video. I have boiled down the error case using the `AVRLDelegateDemo` example. This test case fails for at least iOS 7 and 8. Below is the replacement `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource method`. From the examle code I have found, this should work. What else is needed or what needs to be changed in order for this simple test case to properly function?

I am using http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8 the test stream.

Additionally, are there any known issues with using `AVResourceLoaderDelegate` with `AVPlayerViewController`?

```
- (BOOL) resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{
    NSString* scheme = [[[loadingRequest request] URL] scheme];

    if ([redirectScheme isEqualToString:scheme]) {
        dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(),  ^ {
            NSURLComponents *urlParts = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:loadingRequest.request.URL resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
            urlParts.scheme = httpScheme;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlParts.URL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
            NSString *contentType = urlParts.URL.pathExtension;

            if (0 == [contentType compare:@"m3u8" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
                contentType = @"application/x-mpegURL";
            } else if (0 == [contentType compare:@"ts" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]) {
                contentType = @"video/MP2T";
            }

            NSLog(@"redirtected URL: %@ content type: %@ data length: %lu", urlParts.URL, contentType, data.length);
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentType = contentType;
            loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentLength = data.length;
            [loadingRequest.dataRequest respondWithData:data];
            [loadingRequest finishLoading];
        });
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;

}
```

Comment: According to Apple, passing HLS data directly to the player is unsupported. This technical note is the documentation provided: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECHTTPLIVESTREAMING.

Using a loopback http server is the only recognized way to programmatically provide HLS data to AVPlayer.

Comment: I have no updates beyond successfully implementing the recommended http loopback server. I have had a working player using this approach since February or March.

Comment: Bill, what loopback server did you used? I am trying GCDWebServer but I can't set request header there.

Comment: I started with GCDWebServer but made some heavy modifications. Make sure that your root URL is something like http://localhost:12345/myvideo.m3u8. It is likely that your loopback server is using a non-standard port. If I remember it uses 12345 by default. Perhaps start by just making an NSURLRequest directly against the web server to test that you can get a request to it? You will also need to replicate the standard http server headers for an HLS fragment. I will warn you that it is very finicky with the responses and provides no useful feedback besides a working video or nothing.Good luck!

Comment: Bill, thank you. I am able to get the playlist but video is still not playing. Am I passing it to the AVPlayer correctly? I am making redirect handler with `GCDWebServer` and inside the handler making new `NSURLRequest`, adding header to this request and passing response back to return in the redirect handler. The code: http://pastebin.com/vnYYkchz

Comment: Nothing in your code jumps out at me as wrong. I recommend looking a all traffic between the player when directly connected to the main http server. Review all headers as well as response content. Make sure your http server exactly replicates this stream including all headers and responses. The player does not provide any feedback besides canceling any open requests and shutting down without error codes. It is a painful process to get it working.

Comment: Actually I managed to get it working, I forgot to include correct mime types. Should I post my answer here (as an answer)? Maybe someone will benefit from it.

Comment: Sure, this is a tricky thing to get right. Maybe the answer eventually warrants a github project too.